# Does Drupal 8 entities have any events I can listen to?

Tags: 8, entities, event-subscribers

I know we can use `hook_entity_update()` hook to do something when an entity is updated. But is there an event to listen for node updates/deletes, or other entities such for that matter?

Answer (score 19):

You can't listen to an event. You can either use a hook or implement a method like postSave() in your custom entity.

Here is the order of hooks and other events that happen during an entity save:

- [`Entity::preSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3ApreSave/8.2.x) is called on entity objects, and [`FieldItemListInterface::preSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemListInterface.php/function/FieldItemListInterface%3A%3ApreSave/8.2.x) on field objects.
- [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x)
- [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x)
- Entity is saved to storage.
- [`Entity::postSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3ApostSave/8.2.x) is called on the entity object.
- [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x) (new) or [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x) (update)
- [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/8.2.x) (new) or [`hook_entity_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/8.2.x) (update)

Comment: So entities won't dispatch any events that I can subscribe to? I would have to use a hook?

Comment: Yes, many Drupal specific events are still in hooks. Eventually all hooks will be replaced, see http://drupal.org/node/1509164 and http://drupal.org/node/1972304.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally you would listen for entity related events but these aren't ready yet. See ["Add events for matching entity hooks"](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2551893).

For now, if you're wanting to stay away from hooks, you can use a contrib module: [Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher)

Answer (score 3):

A `node` is an entity type, so `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update(..` is the same as `hook_node_update(..`,

```
function hook_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    //$entity->bundle()  - 'article' 'page'
}
```

or

```
function hook_customentity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity{
    //$entity->bundle()  - 'awesome_entity_bundle'
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x