# How to remove a role after a user adds a payment method in Commerce?

Tags: commerce, event-subscribers

I am trying to set up a subscription-based site in Drupal 8/Commerce 2.

I'm using Commerce Stripe to process payments.  I want to remove a role from a user ("needs to add new card" role) when the user adds a new payment method (credit card via Stripe) on the payment method page (`user/UID/payment-methods`).

I assume I need to [write an event subscriber](https://medium.com/@sumanthkumarc/writing-event-subscriber-for-order-complete-event-in-drupal-8-commerce-2-x-196292330b1c), but I don't know which event to use for adding a payment method.

I tried to read through the code in `commerce/modules/payment/src/EventSubscriber`, but I couldn't find the event I need to hook into to remove the role.

**Background**

When a user's credit card has expired, they need to add a new card (add a new payment method).  In this case, I have flagged the users with a role, **Add new card role**.

Then I show a block to users with the **Add new card role** that says "Please update your card info." with a link to add a card.

However, when the user adds a new card, they still see the block asking them to add a new card, which is confusing.  So I want to immediately remove the **Add new card role** (to hide the block) as soon as the user adds a new card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commerce doesn't offer the (content-)entity create event. You could use a hook ..

- [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create/8.2.x) -> after the entity was created 8will suit your need I guess)
- [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.2.x) -> before the entity will be created

Or setup events for entity creation, see [Does Drupal 8 entities have any events I can listen to?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222057/does-drupal-8-entities-have-any-events-i-can-listen-to)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed to know!  Note that in this case, it turns out that Commerce requires using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert` instead of `create`; see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint from rémy, here's the actual code I used.

Note that for commerce payment methods, you have to use `hook_entity_insert()` specifically instead of `hook_entity_create()` because `hook_entity_create()` gets called when you go to the payment method add page-- even if you immediately go back without entering any information.

```
/**
 * Remove the 'credit_card_update_role' upon adding a credit card.
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
function MYMODULE_commerce_payment_method_insert(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  $account = User::load($uid);
  if ($account->hasRole('credit_card_update')) {
    $account->removeRole('credit_card_update');
    $account->save();
  }
}
```

I added a redirect because by default users are redirected to the payment method edit page, which will result in an access denied error. To avoid this, I send them to the user profile page with a confirmation that the card was added.

```
/**
 * Redirect users to their profile pages after adding a new card.
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_payment_method_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Redirect users to their profile pages.
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_MYMODULE_commerce_payment_method_insert_form_submit';
}

/**
 * Redirect users to their profile pages when submitting the edit form.
 */
function _MYMODULE_commerce_payment_method_insert_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('Thank you for updating your credit card!');
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.user.canonical', ['user' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id()]);
}
```

Comment: Thx for sharing :D